# OneNote 2013 API Sample for Windows Forms app

Tags: onenote

Can I write a simple Hello World app for Windows Forms using the OneNote 2013 API?  I can find no example of this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a published sample right now, as we don't have a Live SDK for desktop windows for doing the necessary auth.

If you can use another library to get an OAUTH token for your Microsoft account, then you can just copy/paste the HTML and service calling code from the Windows Store application.